# Sum of zero sum series

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given $n$ and $k$, I would like to know how to compute$$\sum_{\substack{x_0 ⊕x_1⊕\cdots⊕x_k=0\\x_i≥0,\ 0≤i≤k\\\sum\limits_{i=0}^kx_i≤n-2k}}\binom{n-k-\sum\limits_{i=0}^kx_i}k$$ in $O(nk·\log n)$ time, where $⊕$ is exclusive or.

Comment: This looks easy

Comment: Could you please explain a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out an answer. This paper "[Nim Fractals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5942.pdf)" by Tanya Khovanova and Joshua Xiong gives a recursive formula to count the solutions to $$\begin{cases} x_0 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_k =0 \\\sum_{i=0}^{k}x_i=S\end{cases}$$ in $O(kS)$. Denote the number as $f(k,S)$. We may utilize $f$ to see that the problem reduces to $\sum_{S=0}^{n-2k}\binom{n-k-S}{k}f(k,S)$. The overall complexity is $O(nk\cdot log(n))$.